# Remove the default delete action in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to remove the default delete action in Django admin?
Would the following work?

```
actions = [ ]
```

Comment: For that you can use groups and permissions in django admin.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This works:

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    if 'delete_selected' in actions:
        del actions['delete_selected']
    return actions
```

It's also the recommended way to do this based off Django's documentation below:

[Conditionally enabling or disabling actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#conditionally-enabling-or-disabling-actions)

Comment: for future reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-actions

Comment: This approach effects only the listing view. The delete action is still available in the instance edit page.

Comment: @niekas Yes, But I was already returning false for has_delete_permission, so there be delete button in detail page.

Comment: For a more pythonic way you might use a `try: del actions['delete_selected'] except KeyError: pass`, instead of checking whether it exists beforehand ;)

Comment: That's some dangerous default functionality.

Comment: You may use `actions.pop('delete_selected', None)` instead of `if` check

Answer (score 31):

In your admin class, define [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) to return `False`:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Then, it will not show delete button, and will not allow you to delete objects in admin interface.

Comment: This will remove the delete button, but it wont remove the delete option from the dropdown, which is used to select multiple entries and perform delete action.

Comment: @DawnTCherian, You're right. But deletion is not allowed; attempt will return 403 forbidden response.

Comment: @DawnTCherian, FYI, Your solution will reveal delete button in detail admin page.

Comment: Yes, But I was already returning false for has_delete_permission.

Comment: In django 2.2, this removed both delete option in list display actions and delete button on edit page(form).

Answer (score 15):

You can disable "delete selected" action site-wide:

```
from django.contrib.admin import site
site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

When you need to include this action, add `'delete_selected'` to the action list:

```
actions = ['delete_selected']
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-a-site-wide-action)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove all the action:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    actions = None
```

If you want some specific action:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    actions = ['name_of_action_you_want_to_keep']
```

Comment: The actions = ['name_of_action_you_want_to_keep'] does not work for Django 2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can globally disable bulk delete action and enable for selected models only.

Documentation from [django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.disable_action)

```
# Globally disable delete selected
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')

# This ModelAdmin will not have delete_selected available
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['some_other_action']
    ...

# This one will
class AnotherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['delete_selected', 'a_third_action']
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, really useful to delete it admin-wide!

Answer (score 1):

Giving credit to @DawnTCherian, @tschale and @falsetru

I used:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
  def get_actions(self, request):
      actions = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
      try:
          del actions['delete_selected']
      except KeyError:
        pass
      return actions

  def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
      return False
```

It removes the delete action from the list view and the delete option from the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that model, as a foreign key in some other model.
Then by using `PROTECT` constraint for that foreign key you can disable deletion for that model in Django admin.

For Example,

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    marks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

By adding `PROTECT` constraint to `User` model through the foreign key present in `Exam` model, I have disabled the power (in `Django admin` or elsewhere) to delete students `(User)` who have written exams.